# How to show a start figure of each slice

Tags: android, slice, mpandroidchart

mpandroidchart piechart is very useful. But how can I show a start figure at the beginning of each slice?

I have tried legends but it shows at the middle of each slice but I want to show it at the beginning of each slice. Would you please advise how can I achieve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a start figure at the beginning of each slice"? Can you make a sketch of what you are trying to do, and what your current attempt does (ideally with the code from the current attempt)?